# Jil custom formatting of List/Array

Tags: c#, json, jil

I am using Jil in my Web API project.
I am trying to understand how can I custom serialize the json object when it is array or list such as instead of:

```
{"listKey": ["fasdf", "asdfasdf"]}
```

I will get

```
{"listKey": ["item": {"fsdfdsf", "fadsfasdf"}]
```

How can I achieve custom serialization with Jil?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know from which C# type you could achieve such serialization?